# Unhiding a toolbar doesn't work on a background queue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want the bottom toolbar to disappear when the scroll view stopped scrolling, this is no problem:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
                       self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
                       self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
                       self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
}
```

So this works nicely, but the problem with this approach is that the bottom bar's appearance flickers like it's having a seizure. I don't want that, so I'll have it sleep for one second before it appears again. The problem is that `self.toolbar.hidden` does not respond within a background thread:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"Hello?");
                       sleep(1);
                       self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
                   });
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"Hello?");
                       sleep(1);
                       self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
                   });

}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"Hello?");
                       sleep(1);
                       self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
                   });
}
```

So in this scenario, `self.toolbar.hidden = NO;` does nothing. The NSLogs go through no problem so I thought I'd try this approach but it doesn't work either:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"Hello?");
                       sleep(1);
                       [self unhideToolbar];
                   });
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"Hello?");
                       sleep(1);
                       [self unhideToolbar];
                   });

}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"Hello?");
                       sleep(1);
                       [self unhideToolbar];
                   });
}

-(void)unhideToolbar
{
    NSLog(@"toolbar unhidden");
    self.toolbar.hidden = NO;
}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here... All the NSLogs work no problem, but unhiding the toolbar wants nothing to do with Async functions.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Changing UI should implemented on main queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI changes have to be on the main queue. Try dispatching the back to it like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSLog(@"Hello?");
                       sleep(1);
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           [self unhideToolbar];
                       });
                   });
```